# There is no system tray feature for third party apps i.e. qBittorrent, KeepassXC etc

Tags: system

I can't send third party apps like qBittorrent,KeepassXC to system tray instead it gets closed even when the necessary options are marked to use those on background system tray. 
currently using Elementary OS juno with latest upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

the "problem" is that the Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana is no longer in elementary juno. if you want to install it, try the following link:

[Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://translate.google.cl/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fentornosgnulinux.com%2F2018%2F08%2F15%2Fcomo-instalar-wingpanel-indicator-ayatana-en-elementary-os-juno%2F&edit-text=)

resume:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary

sudo apt update

sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

change OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME; to OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;

Ctrl + O (save change) Ctrl + X (close)

reboot

It worked for me.

Cya.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the 3rd party application working and visible in the system tray, you need to have sni-qt package installed.

Answer (score -1):

There is no system tray in juno, apps will show notification badges on the dock. If you want the system tray back you have to rely on 3rd party workarounds.